# How to expand dataframe to match other dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `A` containing student info:

```
student_id  signup_year age
1           2010        18
2           2011        19
3           2015        25
```

And the following dataframe `B` containing student academic records:

```
student_id  discipline    grade  finishing_date
1           math          18     5/3/2011
1           science       15     5/3/2011
2           math          14     10/4/2013
2           science       13     10/4/2013
3           math          12     11/5/2016
3           science       11     12/6/2016
```

In table `B` I want to calculate the grade of the student in their first year, with the condition:

```
grade = 0 if finishing_year - signup_year > 1 else grade
```

The output (table `B`) would be:

```
student_id  discipline    grade  finishing_date
1           math          18     5/3/2011
1           science       15     5/3/2011
2           math          0      10/4/2013
2           science       0      10/4/2013
3           math          12     11/5/2016
3           science       11     12/6/2016
```

The problem is that I want this operation to be vectorized (my dataset contains +500 000 samples)

What I have tried:

```
def vectorized(A, B):

    B["grade"] = np.where(
        pd.DatetimeIndex(B["finishing_date"]).year - A["signup_year"]
        > 1,
        B["grade"] * 0,
        B["grade"],
    )
    return grades_df
```

However, this does not work as `A["signup_year"]` does not have the same length as `B["finishing_date"]).year`.
How can I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for get `Series` with same length like `B` by `student_id`:

```
B["grade"] = np.where(
       pd.to_datetime(B["finishing_date"]).dt.year - 
       B["student_id"].map(A.set_index('student_id')['signup_year'])
       > 1,
       0,
       B["grade"])

print (B)
   student_id discipline  grade finishing_date
0           1       math     18       5/3/2011
1           1    science     15       5/3/2011
2           2       math      0      10/4/2013
3           2    science      0      10/4/2013
4           3       math     12      11/5/2016
5           3    science     11      12/6/2016
```

**Detail**:

```
print (B["student_id"].map(A.set_index('student_id')['signup_year']))
0    2010
1    2010
2    2011
3    2011
4    2015
5    2015
Name: student_id, dtype: int64
```

Another idea is use `merge` with left join:

```
B["grade"] = np.where(
       pd.to_datetime(B["finishing_date"]).dt.year - 
       B.merge(A, on="student_id", how='left')['signup_year']
       > 1,
       0,
       B["grade"])
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Still didn't test it, but marking as a solution for now